# Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have configured the quartz scheduler in spring boot. I was able to get the cron scheduled job run every 1 min. So the job is supposed to start right after startup. But the behavior is not the same always. I can see the following msg keeps getting logged once application startup is complete `HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection. (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.` I don't know if it has something to do with the database configuration. There is only one job expected to run.

I also tried adding `hikari.max-lifetime=50000` & `connection-timeout=60000` but no change. Just that the above message stops getting logged. Please share your thoughts.
Below is the start-up log

```
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.bhi.sop.pip.soppipApplication","msg":"Starting SoppipApplication using Java 11.0.11 on B720LL with PID 5532 (D:\\Projects\\sop-pip-app\\target\\classes started by U55097 in D:\\Projects\\sop-pip-app)","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:21.999"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.bhi.sop.pip.SoppipApplication","msg":"The following profiles are active: dev","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:21.999"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol","msg":"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-9090\"]","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:23.798"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","msg":"Starting service [Tomcat]","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:23.798"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine","msg":"Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:23.799"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/Sop-pip-app]","msg":"Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:23.877"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Starting...","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:24.080"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Start completed.","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:26:27.612"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.bhi.sop.pip.jSop.IsoClient","msg":"Connected with host:216.76.27.250 , Sopt:20500, status:false","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:22.001"}
{"level":"WARN","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=47s164ms774µs400ns).","thread":"HikariPool-1 housekeeper","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:44.898"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory","msg":"Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:49.806"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl","msg":"Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:49.821"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler","msg":"Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:49.821"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin","msg":"Registering Quartz shutdown hook.","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:49.821"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler","msg":"Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'Sop-pip-clustered-scheduler' with instanceId 'B720LL1633258669806'\n  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.\n  NOT STARTED.\n  Currently in standby mode.\n  Number of jobs executed: 0\n  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.\n  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.\n","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:50.088"}
{"env":"dev","host":"B720LL","level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory","msg":"Quartz scheduler 'Sop-pip-clustered-scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:50.088"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory","msg":"Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:50.088"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler","msg":"JobFactory set to: com.bhi.sop.pip.job.SchedulerJobFactory@663e89b2","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:51.083"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol","msg":"Starting ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-9090\"]","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:55.133"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler","msg":"Scheduler Sop-pip-clustered-scheduler_$_LIK1633258669806 started.","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:57.326"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"com.bhi.sop.pip.SoppipApplication","msg":"Started SoppipApplication in 95.991 seconds (JVM running for 98.4)","thread":"restartedMain","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:57.374"}
{"level":"INFO","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/Sop-pip-app]","msg":"Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'","thread":"RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.29.216","time":"2021-10-03 16:27:57.795"}
{"level":"WARN","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@da17b10 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.","thread":"QuartzScheduler_pip-sop-clustered-scheduler_ClusterManager","time":"2021-10-03 16:55:57.498"}
{"level":"WARN","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase","msg":"HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@642b1bc3 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.","thread":"QuartzScheduler_pip-sop-clustered-scheduler_ClusterManager","time":"2021-10-03 16:55:57.498"}
```

Application yaml

```
  quartz:
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
      org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: sop-pip-clustered-scheduler
      org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 3
      org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
      org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: true
      org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
      org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: qrtz_
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown: TRUE
      org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime: 5000

    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    job-store-type: jdbc
```

Here's what's relevant from pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Look in PostgreSQL's log file for seemingly related messages.  If non, then maybe turn on log_connections and log_disconnections for a while.  For something that only runs once a minute, there isn't much point in using a connection pool anyway

Comment: @jjanes The job in reality is supposed to run every night. But I scheduled to run every minute just for testing purposes and to make sure it works. Will check the logs and get back.

Comment: @continuousLearner Facing similar issue. Have you got the solution?